# can we change the font color of a field based upon the value of another field?

Tags: reporting-services

I know we can change the font color of a field based upon the value of the same field as follows..

```
=IIF(Fields!Field-name.Value<100,"red","green")
```

writing this expression in the font property of particular field.

But how can we change the font color of one field basing on another field's values? Is it possible to change in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can reference any fields in the expression; it will use the value(s) in the current scope.

With some simple data:

[image]

And a simple table:

[image]

I have set the `FieldValue2` textbox to have its **Color** based on an expression using the `FieldValue1` value:

[image]

```
=IIf(Fields!FieldValue1.Value < 100, "Red", "Green")
```

Which works as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use CSS, because CSS does not allow variables.

May I suggest instead using SASS, which does support variables, and using javascript to change said variables.

See a guide for SASS [here](http://sass-lang.com/guide)

Comment: No, I'm not using CSS. I want this in SSRS. Reporting services in SQL.

Comment: Sorry, would it be possible, next time, to put it in the question?